# How to conjugate a verb in NLTK given POS tag?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Given a POS tag, such as VBD, how can I conjugate a verb to match with NLTK?

e.g.

```
VERB: go
POS: VBD
RESULT: went
```

Comment: Are you talking about the POS tag so that you make sure you're conjugating a verb and not a noun or an adjective, for instance?

Answer (score 21):

NLTK doesn't currently provide conjugations. Pattern-en and [nodebox](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Linguistics#verb_conjugation) do conjugations.

Sometimes the examples in the pattern-en website don't work as shown. This worked for me:

```
>>> from pattern.en import conjugate
>>> verb = "go"
>>> conjugate(verb, 
...     tense = "past",           # INFINITIVE, PRESENT, PAST, FUTURE
...    person = 3,                # 1, 2, 3 or None
...    number = "singular",       # SG, PL
...      mood = "indicative",     # INDICATIVE, IMPERATIVE, CONDITIONAL, SUBJUNCTIVE
...    aspect = "imperfective",   # IMPERFECTIVE, PERFECTIVE, PROGRESSIVE 
...   negated = False)            # True or False
u'went'
>>>
```

**NOTE**

It seems like `conjugate` only outputs when the tense doesn't require an auxiliary verb. For instance, in Spanish the (singular first person) future of *ir* is *iré*. In English, the future of *go* is formed with the auxiliary *will* and the infinitive *go*, resulting in *will go*. In the code below, *iré* is output, but not *will go*.

```
>>> from pattern.es import conjugate as conjugate_es
>>> verb = "ir"
>>> conjugate_es(verb, tense = "future")
u'ir\xe1'
>>> from pattern.en import conjugate as conjugate_en
>>> verb = "go"
>>> conjugate_en(verb, tense = "future")
>>>
```

Comment: does this mean that NLTK does NOT do verb conjugation?

Comment: exactly :) (I'm open to being wrong, but I or anyone else that I know around here haven't found a way to do it!)

Comment: @arturomp, I was trying to use the future tense for pattern.en. Does it work for you cause it returns nothing to me.

Comment: yea that's interesting - it seems to have to do with languages and whether you need an auxiliary verb to form the tense (like _will_ in English)! in Spanish, on the other hand, you actually conjugate the verb to form the future without using an auxiliary verb, so in that case it seems to work! I've updated my answer to note this, but I really feel like this should be in the docs

Comment: @macmania314 you may also want to look at the different test files for English and Spanish, for instance, for a bit more evidence about this: [Spanish test](https://github.com/clips/pattern/blob/820cccf33c6ac4a4f1564a273137171cfa6ab7cb/test/test_es.py) and [English test](https://github.com/clips/pattern/blob/820cccf33c6ac4a4f1564a273137171cfa6ab7cb/test/test_en.py)

Answer (score 1):

I used MontyLingua for word inflexion and conjugation.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MontyLingua/2.1

```
    mlg = MontyLingua.MontyNLGenerator.MontyNLGenerator()
    mlg.conjugate_verb(verb,mode)
```

More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MontyLingua

Comment: Just checked out pattern and it looks very good; I'll consider replacing my MontyLingua code!