# How to get lexical texts for a given word in python using nltk

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet, lexical-analysis

I have a text like

```
 my_text="Bill"
```

I want the lexical texts for my string, my desired output is

```
  my_output=["Bill","Billing","Billed"]
```

Comment: Are you looking for conjugated words, or just words that match you "sub-word" ?

Comment: can you help me with both

Comment: for conjugated words, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942096/how-to-conjugate-a-verb-in-nltk-given-pos-tag